# Where to store microservice logs?

Tags: logging, microservices

I am looking for the most effective way to store logs for the following scenario.

Microservice layer for several e-commerce related apps.

I want to store every request and response from each app into the microservice layer.

Where would you store all this data? (can be paid solution)

How could I easily query all this data? (can be paid solution)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to pay for services like [Atlassian Sentry](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1219432/sentry-for-jira?tab=overview&hosting=cloud), you have your logs indexed and it's easy to search the logs very quickly.

There are other alternatives too, check them on alternative.to :D